# Selecting non duplicate variations from sql results

Tags: mysql

I have one table

```
|| *content_value* || *content_const* || *language_language_id* ||
|| subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||                      1 ||
|| subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||                      1 ||
|| title_1         || heading_1       ||                      1 ||
|| title_2         || heading_2       ||                      1 ||
|| title_1         || heading_1       ||                      2 ||
|| title_1         || heading_1       ||                      2 ||
|| title_1         || heading_1       ||                      3 ||
|| title_2         || heading_2       ||                      3 ||
```

I need inserting back to the table rows with newly added content_const but only with variations with language_language_id which not exist yet. i have a query:

```
SELECT a.language_language_id
     , b.content_value
     , b.content_const 
  FROM content a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM .content  
        GROUP 
           BY .content.content_const 
       HAVING COUNT(.content.content_const) = 1
     ) b
 WHERE a.language_language_id != b.language_language_id
```

with results:

```
    || *language_language_id* || *content_value* || *content_const* ||
    ||                      3 || subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||
    ||                      3 || subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||
    ||                      2 || subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||
    ||                      2 || subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||
    ||                      2 || subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||
    ||                      2 || subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||
    ||                      3 || subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||
    ||                      3 || subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||
```

the result is good, but i need only rows without duplicated language_language_id and content_const variations. resp. this result:

```
    || *language_language_id* || *content_value* || *content_const* ||
    ||                      3 || subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||
    ||                      3 || subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||
    ||                      2 || subtitle_2      || subtitle_2      ||
    ||                      2 || subtitle_1      || sub_1           ||
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What is '.' in '.content'?

Comment: nothing, my mysql client giving me the tablelist when i begining writing the query with "."

Comment: Your client decides your table names for you? Anyway, it seems DISTINCT is what you're after - if that query is really what you want!

Comment: table list from existing names in the database...
is there problem with the query, you have a better idea?

Comment: There are problems with the query. Perhaps most importantly, your PRIMARY KEY is formed on ALL the columns in the table (or, at the very least, on [content_value,language_language_id]). However your GROUP BY only includes one of the non-aggregated columns. This will lead to indeterminate (and possibly erroneous) results.

Comment: ok, then what can i do? i got the good results with the query
`SELECT * FROM .content  GROUP BY .content.content_const HAVING COUNT(.content.content_const) = 1`

`|| *content_id* || *content_value* || *content_const* || *language_language_id* ||
|| 23 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 1 ||
|| 24 || subtitle_2 || sub_2 || 1 ||`

after that i need inserting back these values to the table, only with language codes what already exits in the table but no with that values... sorry for my bad english... ist this understable?